# Disabled TEdit Font Colour

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have an application having one `TEdit` which is disabled when the application runs. After some calculations it will be enabled. My requirement is to set the `Font.Color` of this disabled `TEdit` as Blue instead of Grey (Disabled Font Color).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Peter Below's two suggestions for accomplishing your objective on Torry's Delphi Pages at this [link](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1950). Judging from your comment about what you Googled, his first suggestion will be simpler for you to implement. Drop a TPanel on a form and drag a TEdit onto the TPanel (i.e., TPanel is TEdit's parent. Then drop a Button on the form to simulate when your calculations are done.

```
procedure TForm1.btnToggleEnabledClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Panel1.Enabled then
  begin
    {Calcs are not done, so disable the TEdit}
    Panel1.Enabled := false;
    Edit1.Font.Color := clBlue;
    Edit1.Text := 'Calcs not done';
  end
  else
  begin
    {Calcs are done, so enable the TEdit}
    Panel1.Enabled := true;
    Edit1.Font.Color := clWindowText;
    Edit1.Text := 'Calcs all done';
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is not supported by the standard `TEdit`. You could set the edit to ReadOnly instead of Disabled - this way the font color is preserved but user can't change the value of the edit. Ie to "disable" the edit

```
Edit1.ReadOnly := True;
Edit1.Font.Color := clBlue;
```

and to enable it again

```
Edit1.ReadOnly := False;
Edit1.Font.Color := clWindowText;
```

Comment: I only need to set Disbled TEdit Font Color it may be ReadOnly or not. I Googled, some solutions are there, but not understandable to me.

Comment: Setting the `TEdit.Enabled` property to `False` implicitally makes the edit field read-only to the user. So there really is no need to use the `TEdit.Enabled` property when the `TEdit.ReadOnly` property accomplishes the same effect. I use this approach in my apps all the time, it works fine. I even take it a step further by changing the `TEdit.Color` property whenever I change the `TEdit.ReadOnly` property so the user can visually see that the edit field has been "disabled", eg: `Edit1.Color := clBtnFace; Edit1.ReadOnly := True;` and `Edit1.Color := clWindow; Edit1.ReadOnly := False;`